# Generate Local Resource fails on asp.net mvc views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, localization, resources

Trying to localize a large existing MVC website, using Visual Studio 2010, MVC 4.

If I switch a view to the design view and then select Tools -> Generate Local Resource, none of the html text is pushed to a resource file and all I get is an app_localresources/pagename.aspx.resx file with one useless entry:

```
 <data name="PageResource1.Title" xml:space="preserve">
     <value>&lt;asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /&gt;</value>
 </data>
```

Is there a setting that I'm missing that prevents this from working?

Or do we have to manually strip all the html text out of this large existing mvc website manually?

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more googling, it appears that the VS tool for Generate Local Resource only runs on actual web form .net controls, and ignores all of the other aspx code and html text, so it's pretty useless for an MVC app.

We're going with a different route, which is to create a separate folder for copies of all of the view files, and have the app switch the view path at run time based on the user's selected culture.

We will just hand the whole separate folder of view pages to the translators and hope they don't screw up the aspx code too much. O_o And then the files will go back to the designers to fix the layouts. O_o

Otherwise, it'll take weeks to strip out all of the strings into resource files, and then the translators won't have the context of what they're translating, and the designers will have a fit because the layout will get screwed up.